# d3.js : not showing two charts in two different widget of sonarqube

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plugins, sonarqube

I put my json file in server folder (where the server runs) which contain data about d3.js chart (for different project different file are there). sonarqube working properly if we open only one widget chart render properly but when I open another widget both charts disappear. I am not gatting any javascript error and error in log file. I don't want to use  Metrics to store data.

only I getting this in log file :

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The :http_only option in ActionController::Response#set_cookie has been renamed. Please use :httponly instead. (called from []= at D:/sonar/sonarqube-5.1.1/sonarqube-5.1.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/actionpack-2.3.15/lib/action_controller/cookies.rb:84)

Comment: are you using chrome? try in firefox, I got errors in firefox that didnt show up in chrome

Comment: thank you. now it shows one chart if we open two widget in firefox.but now i get this error :Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: [object Object] http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch in require.js:1:794